# Алгоритм генеалогическое дерево

Tags: алгоритм, php, mysql

Есть задумка сделать вывод данных генеалогического дерева. Допустим что данные вводятся сверху вниз и нет пока дополнительных ответвлений, просто ёлка, т.е. ни любовниц ни отчимов пока нет. Вопросы следующие

```
 1. Каким образом осуществить привязку между поколениями и внутри поколений?
 1.2 Допустим, заполняя таблицу я сразу же привязываю супруга к ID супруги, а в строке супруги указываю ID потомства, но тогда позже возникнут затруднения при указании детей не от данного супруга.
 2. Как лучше заполнять базу? Сделать 1 таблицу с данными о людях и 2 таблицу с данными о связях или тут можно придумать что-то?
```

Может у кого то есть готовый подходящий скрипт, или кто то натыкался на похожий алгоритм? Буду рад любой помощи))

Хорошо, делаю таблицу `families`

```
    famID   int(11) // PRIMARY KEY
    wedding date //Дата свадьбы
    divorce date //Дата развода
    dive       tinyint(1) //Состояние брака
    father   int(11) // ID номер из individuals 
    mother  int(11) // ID номер из individuals
```

И таблицу `individuals`

```
    1   ID      int(11) // PRIMARY KEY
    2   name        varchar(50) //Имя
    3   firstname   varchar(50) //Фамилия
    4   gender      char(1) //Пол
    5   birth       date //Дата рождения
    6   death       date //Дата смерти
    7   comment     varchar(200) //Комментарии
    8   famC        int(11) //famID
```

Итак, `families` будет отображать все связи, если это муж с женой, то присваивается `famID` номер. Если их ребенок, то в `individuals` записывается в `famC` номер семьи родителей. Вроде должно работать...

Comment: Оно не должно. Оно будет работать. Эта схема исключает рождение детей у родителей, которые живут например в гражданском браке=) Или которые вообще никогда не поженятся. Я бы individuals.famC заменил на 2 поля: id отца и id матери. А в families указывать не отца и мать, а мужа и жену.

Comment: Ну как бы если есть связь famID.families, то уже их дети уже будут иметь в famC.individuals  отметку. Впринципе, это просто ни чего не меняющая перемена места в таблицах. Другой вопрос, как выводить эти связи? Есть задумка использовать заготовленные картинки прямых линий и уголков, алгоритм конечно получится длинный, но по моему надежней чем способом прорисовки линий библиотекой GD.

Comment: Как выводить - тут только Вашей фантазией дело ограничено. О себе скажу - ни за что бы не стал юзать GD. Куда прозрачнее использование css+html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вариант Вы можете в таблице person хранить всю нужную Вам информацию о человеке, в том числе и id-шники его родителей (foreign key). В другой таблице хранить "свидетельства о браке" в одной колонке id мужа, в другой - id жены. При таком раскладе Вы всё что угодно сможете вытворять. SQL - штука гибкая. Надеюсь помог.

Answer (score 0):

Для обработки генеалогических данных традиционно используется специально разработанный для этого язык - Пролог

используйте графовые БД

neo4j как самая известная, библиотеки-коннекторы есть подо все что шевелится